# AddAllAttributes method spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have two lists

```
List<User> list_of_users=new ArrayList<User>();
List<String> list_of_attributes=new ArrayList<String>();
```

When i try to use the following lines of code:

```
model.addAttribute("takeattributes",list_of_users);
model.addAttribute("takeattributes",list_of_attributes);
```

I realise that it keeps only the second list (list_of_attributes) and the first deleted.
I was wondering how to keep both of these two lists in the model.Is this possible to be happened?Is the AddAllAttributes method what i need?If yes can anyone explain me how the AddAllAttributes method is working.I look at the spring mvc documentation but i didn't really understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The model is essentially a `Map` with unique keys. You really should define two unique keys:

```
model.addAttribute("users", list_of_users);
model.addAttribute("attributes", list_of_attributes);
```

The first argument serves as the identifier to which you can reference each respective list in your GUI.

Comment: i'm not really interested on changing the name of the attributes. Could you explain me, in this specific occasion how can i merge the lists?

Comment: @NickRobertson, no I cannot, `User` and `String` are not compatible. *Really*, you should consider renaming one attribute, e.g. `users` and `attributes`.